# Adding a legend to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below dataset;

| Player | Goals | Shots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Regan Charles-Cook | 10 | 32 |
| Tony Watt | 9 | 36 |
| Bruce Anderson | 8 | 26 |
| Liam Boyce | 8 | 44 |
| Kyogo Furuhashi | 8 | 31 |
| Alfredo Morelos | 8 | 80 |
| Christian Ramirez | 8 | 41 |
| Liel Abada | 7 | 57 |
| Martin Boyle | 7 | 43 |
| Kevin van Veen | 7 | 45 |

I am attempting a dumbbell chart and so far have the following code;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

theme_set(theme_bw())

read_excel("SPL_Goals.xlsx")

data <- read_excel("SPL_Goals.xlsx")

data %>%
  #the below code sets out the initial plot template without the data
  ggplot(aes(x= Goals, xend = Shots, y= Player)) +
  #below code inputs the data viz on to the plot
  geom_dumbbell(
    size = 1.5, color = "black", size_x = 10,   #size=1.5 dictates black line size
    size_xend = 3, colour_x = "green",
    colour_xend = "red") +
  labs(
    title = "Scotland; Goals v Shots",           #add title
    subtitle = "Top 10; Matchday 22",                         #add subtitle
    x = "Total", y = "Player"
  )+
  geom_text(aes(label = Goals))
```

This produces the below chart;
[image]

My query is how do I order the chart so Goals (the green circle) is ascending and also add a legend to show Goals (green) and Shots (red)? I have tried mutate, reorder and fct_reorder but I am doing something wrong as none of these are working.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. You might benefit from basic ggplot tutorials. http://cookbook-r.com/Graphs/  or https://ggplot2-book.org/

Comment: @tjebo I’ve reopened this, the duplicate does *not* explain how to solve either of OP’s issues.

Comment: @tjebo I have looked, yes. I don’t see anything that’s obviously applicable to OP. Their issue isn’t just different shapes but that their different shapes have fundamentally different meanings. Of course you can reshape the data as required *if you already know how to do this*. But it’s non-trivial. I’m fairly sure that the link, as is, doesn’t help OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the ordering of the y-axis, you need to `reorder` your y-axis variable based on the value that you want to order *by*. In your case, this means `reorder`ing `Player` based on `Goals`:

```
data %>% mutate(Player = reorder(Player, Goals) %>% …
```

Next, creating a manual legend for `ggdumbell` doesn’t seem possible, or at least it isn’t obvious to me how. However, if you draw the chart manually, you can add a manual legend. This requires several things:

1. Create the dumbbell shape manually by plotting a `geom_segment` and two `geom_point`s.
2. Creating an `aes` for the colour, which will get mapped into the legend
3. Create a manual color scale which we use to translate the mapping into actual colours, and to draw the legend.

Putting all that together:

```
data %>%
  mutate(Player = reorder(Player, Goals)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Goals, y = Player)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Shots, yend = Player), color = "black", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Goals"), size = 10) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Shots, color = "Shots"), size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Goals), color = "black") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(Goals = "green", Shots = "red"),
    guide = guide_legend(title = "", override.aes = list(size = 3))
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Scotland; Goals v Shots",
    subtitle = "Top 10; Matchday 22",
    x = "Total", y = "Player"
  )
```

We use `override.aes` to specify a fixed size for the points inside the legend. Without this, ‘ggplot2’ would overlay two points of different sizes. We also set the title of the legend to `""` because the default title would be “colour”, and a title doesn’t seem necessary here.

[image: first]

I’ve also used `theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")` to generate the image above.

The above is still ordered slightly weirdly, because for players with the same number of goal shots the ordering is still arbitrary. I would probably order those players by (descending) attempted goal shots. That is, it’s better for a player to have scored many goals with the least attempts.

Unfortunately `reorder` doesn’t support such an ordering directly. Instead, we need to resort to `arrange`ing the entire table and then reorder players by their row number:

```
data %>%
  arrange(Goals, -Shots) %>%
  mutate(Player = reorder(Player, row_number())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Goals, y = Player)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Shots, yend = Player), color = "black", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Goals"), size = 10) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Shots, color = "Shots"), size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Goals), color = "black") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(Goals = "green", Shots = "red"),
    guide = guide_legend(title = "", override.aes = list(size = 3))
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Scotland; Goals v Shots",
    subtitle = "Top 10; Matchday 22",
    x = "Total", y = "Player"
  )
```

[image: second]

Comment: Thank you @KonradRudolph - this is a big help, the extra explanation will also improve my R understanding.

Comment: Thank you @tjebo for the tutorials link.